# How to get nearest coastal point from google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How do i get nearest coastal point in google map. I have read in google Places API that we can query for geographical locations.

Any help??

Comment: you can maybe try with elevation. 0m will equal sea-level

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Google Elevation API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/

You can do request for any location on the map. You can possibly tweak this API to find the nearest 0m elevation from a custom location.